# Use Variable that contains Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to store regex in a variable to be used multiple times. For example, I have some regex to delimit a number using commas https://jsfiddle.net/Le7wayee/:

```
var numAcquired = 1400000    
numAcquired = numAcquired.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
```

The output of this is of course the string `1,400,000`, but I use this many times on a number of variables containing differing numbers/lengths , and I'd prefer to, for simplicity's sake, store it in a variable as opposed to explicitly writing it every time. Is this something that's possible?

Comment: `var re = new RegExp('\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))', 'g');`?

Comment: You already know how to declare variables, and how to produce regex objects. Then it shouldn't be much difficult.

Comment: Valid question.  Thanks for asking.  Remember to accept the best answer!  @Oriol, not everything obvious to you is obvious to everyone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign the regexp to a variable:

```js
var numberCommasRegexp = /\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g;

var numAcquired = 1400000;
numAcquired = numAcquired.toString().replace(numberCommasRegexp, ',');

alert(numAcquired);
```

But instead of writing the `replace()` expression all the time, you could just define a function to do this.

```js
function addCommas(number) {
  return number.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
var numAcquired = 14000000;
numAcquired = addCommas(numAcquired);
alert(numAcquired);
```

Comment: hah, silly me I assumed it was something more than that; when I tried it before it didn't work.. must have done something wrong the first time

Answer (score 0):

[`RegExp` is a native type in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), and the form that you're already using -- `/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g` -- is its *literal* form. Thus, you can assign that value to a variable like you would *any* literal form:

```
var pattern = /\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g
```

And then reuse that value in any method of `String` that accepts a pattern:

```
numAcquired.toString().replace(pattern, ',');
```

If you'd like a runnable example, see my colleague's answer that does the same.

Comment: RegExp is not a type.